# Using Android L animations for switching between activities

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, material-design

How can I use some of the Android L animations for switching between activities? I can only find information about [defining custom animations](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html).

I cannot find any documentation about the following animation between the Inbox and Settings activities in the Android Developer Documentation.

[image: Gmail animation]

I have extracted the anim files from Gmail but when using the following, the activities only slide up and down, and there is no Z movement (depth).

```
activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.abc_slide_in_bottom, R.anim.abc_slide_out_top);
```

You can find the anim files used [here](https://gist.github.com/jackwilsdon/e725186b0e18b615eee1).

Comment: Please post the R.anim.

Comment: I have attached the anim folder to the post.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like Gmail uses the [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) class to create animations, so I had to create my own version.

`swap_in_bottom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:startOffset="200"
    android:zAdjustment="top">

    <alpha
        android:duration="150"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" />

    <translate
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromYDelta="100.0%p"
        android:toYDelta="0.0" />

</set>
```

`swap_out_bottom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:zAdjustment="bottom">

    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%p"
        android:pivotY="50%p"
        android:toXScale="0.9"
        android:toYScale="0.9" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.5" />

    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromYDelta="0.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:startOffset="100"
        android:toYDelta="20.0%p" />

</set>
```

And the code to use it;

```
 overridePendingTransition(R.anim.swap_in_bottom, R.anim.swap_out_bottom);
```

Here's how my custom animation looks (a lot smoother on the device);

[image]

Comment: @Jack Wilsdon But how we can do top to bottom instead of bottom to top? can you help?